# How to get PDF Version with ghostscript (GS) on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript

I can change the PDF version with:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

How I can get the original PDF version of input.pdf using gs?

Comment: KenS answered the "change" PDF version bit. To get the (stated!, not necessarily correct!) version of your input.pdf, use this command: `head -n 1 input.pdf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't 'changing' the PDF version there. When you interpret a PDF file with Ghostscript it doesn't just play around with bits of it. It fully interprets the input, creating a sequence of graphics primitives.

These are then sent to the 'device' for processing. For rendering devices (eg png16m) these are rendered to a bitmap. For the pdfwrite device, it takes those primitives and converts them into new PDF operations. The output should be visually the same, but it is not the same sequence of PDF operations as were in the original file.

So what you are actually doing is creating a brand new PDF file, which is compatible with version 1.4 of the PDF specification. In this case that means it doesn't use any features of later versions of the spec, it may not use any 1.4 features either, its just guaranteed not to need a version higher than that.

You don't need GS to find out the existing level of a PDF file, its in the header of the file. PDF files should begin with '%PDF-x.y' though they are considered valid if the header appears anywhere in the first 1024 bytes (IIRC) of the file. x is the major version and y is the minor version of the specification required by this PDF file. SO a 1.4 file would begin %PDF-1.4

However, you should be aware that some PDF files are 'economical with the truth', especially ones which have been edited, and don't always declare the correct version required.